# Get email body text without reply details - ActionMailbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm implementing ActionMailbox with Rails 6. In my process function, I grab the details of the email and save them for future reference. ActionMailbox allows me to reference the email body text like this:

```
mail.text_part.body.decoded
```

This works fine, but when a user is replying to an email, the function returns their message reply plus the message text they were replying to which looks something like this:

```
Hello, this is a response. On Jan 4th, 2021 example@example.com said Please respond to this message.
```

I'm looking to grab just the text "Hello, this is a response.".

I want to retrieve just the text from their reply without the text from the email the user was replying to. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: All of this code is in the [`mail` gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) however you are reading the `text_part` and a plain text email likely will not have any form of (or knowledge of) this separation.